# Error running ruby code containing a regular expression and index value

Tags: ruby, watir

Getting the following error running a ruby script:
C:/Ruby/test3.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
...41afa164b242__Rate/ => :index 1).set "00.10"
...

`@b.text_field(:id, /Contracts_[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}__ContractTranslationQualities_[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}__ContractPrices_[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}__ContractPriceWordRates_0ec7c68c-663a-40aa-9ab6-41afa164b242__Rate/ => :index 1).set "00.10"`

BTW the regex is checked against the html code using Rubular.com and it checks out. I am successfully using this method in other pages that do not contain multiple elements with the same id. However on this page I am testing there are 4 text fields with this id so I need to index unless you have another suggestion. Thanks for the help.

```
<td>
<div class="symbol-left-inner-addon">
<span class="CurrencySymbol" title="USD">$</span>
<input id="Contracts_b05b4efc-fc08-427b-9319-6a25409eded1__ContractTranslationQualities_f056e412-af83-4965-8fbd-c516f17fb8cf__ContractPrices_9d79ae47-3295-4cbc-9ed5-5b96e53ed1c1__ContractPriceWordRates_b5356ba9-bdc8-49a8-855a-8c2271078f61__Rate" class="form-control numericInput text-right valid" type="text" value="0.00" name="Contracts[b05b4efc-fc08-427b-9319-6a25409eded1].ContractTranslationQualities[f056e412-af83-4965-8fbd-c516f17fb8cf].ContractPrices[9d79ae47-3295-4cbc-9ed5-5b96e53ed1c1].ContractPriceWordRates[b5356ba9-bdc8-49a8-855a-8c2271078f61].Rate" data-val-required="The Rate field is required." data-val-number="The field Rate must be a number." data-val="true">
</div>
</td>  

                ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple locators, it has to be passed as a Hash. It would look like (with the ID condensed for readability):

```
@b.text_field(:id => /Contracts/, :index => 1).set "00.10"
```

Or if you prefer the newer style:

```
@b.text_field(id: /Contracts/, index: 1).set "00.10"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I am now getting an error unable to find element. I will edit the question to include the html.

Comment: The regular expression being used ends with `0ec7c68c-663a-40aa-9ab6-41afa164b242__Rate` while the id attribute value ends with `b5356ba9-bdc8-49a8-855a-8c2271078f61__Rate`, The GUIDs are not the same. It seems like you are over specifying the id value. Since it is the rate field, I would expect `@b.text_field(id: /__Rate$/)` would be sufficient.